# Graphviz was not available to create the requested graph. (Java, Eclipse, Windows)

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, graphviz

I am using schemecrawler library in in Java to produce an image file. But when running the Java program on Windows computer it gives me this error:

```
Graphviz was not available to create the requested graph. Please reinstall 
Graphviz, and make it available on the system PATH. Meanwhile, a .dot text file 
has been created instead. This .dot file can be opened in any Graphviz file 
viewer.
```

I have installed Graphviz for Windows but I don't know exactly what I have to configure now to make it work. Does someone know how to do this? It would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow Graphviz doesn't set the system PATH so I had to do it manually. :)